# Is a derivation a proof?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

Is there a difference between "derivation" and "proof"? I imagine a derivation is a type of proof but that proofs are perhaps more general. Although then again, I suppose every proof should be derivable from some axioms, so perhaps there is no difference?

Comment: In my experience, "derivation" is a special kind of proof, of an equation or similarly succinct statement.

Comment: To me, derivation might be a synonym for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof

Comment: A good answer would require you to specify *exactly* what you mean by "proof" and "derivation."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See for example :

- Richard Kaye, [The Mathematics of Logic : A guide to completeness theorems and their applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&pg=PA25) (2007), page 24-25 :

> Formal systems are kinds of mathematical games with strings of symbols and precise rules. They mimic the idea of a ‘proof’.
>
> **Definition 3.1** Let [$\Sigma$ a set of strings and $\tau$ a string]. We write $\Sigma \vdash \tau$ to mean that it is possible to write down $\tau$ in a finite number of steps that follow the rules of the game for $\Sigma$.
>
> If $\Sigma \vdash \tau$ then there is a list of strings that can be written down in the game, each of which is written down according to one of the [...] rules, the last one
>   in the list being $\tau$. Sometimes this list of strings is called a formal proof or
>   formal *derivation* of $\tau$ from strings in $\Sigma$ following the rules given.
>
> Thus $\Sigma \vdash \tau$ can be expressed as saying ‘there is a formal proof of $\tau$ from strings in $\Sigma$’.

---

In other books, you can find "*deduction*" used with the same meaning; see :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA111) (2nd ed - 2001), page 111 :

> **DEFINITION**. A *deduction of* $\varphi$ *from* $\Gamma$ is a finite sequence $\langle α_0,\ldots,α_n \rangle$ of formulas such that $α_n$ is $\varphi$ and for each $k ≤ n$, either
>
> > (a) $α_k$ is in $\Gamma \cup \Lambda$ [where $\Lambda$ is the set of *logical axioms*], or
> >
> > (b) $α_k$ is obtained by *modus ponens* [the *rule of inference* of the *calculus*, or *proof system*] from two earlier formulas in the sequence; that is, for some $i,j < k$, $α_j$ is $α_i \to α_k$.
>
> If such a deduction exists, we say that $\varphi$ is *deducible from* $\Gamma$, or that
>   $\varphi$ is a *theorem* of $\Gamma$, and we write $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

---

In conclusion, a *derivation* is a "formalized" proof, i.e. it is the "formal counterpart" of a mathematical proof according to the language and rules of a [formal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system).