# Clarifying the definition of a logical system on wikipedia

Tags: logic

> Logical system is a deductive system together with additional (non-logical) axioms and a semantics. An example of a logical system is Peano arithmetic.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system)

Can you please explain what is non-logical axioms and a semantics in this context?

Comment: A logical axiom is a formula that is true in every interpretation, like e.g. $\forall x (x=x)$. A non-logical axiom is a formula that is true in some interpretation. Example: the [Peano axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) $\forall x\ (0\neq S(x))$ is true in $\mathbb N$ but not in every interpretation.

Comment: Having said that, no clear-cut difference

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What about semantics? Does the deductive system include semantics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per discussions on previous [similar posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057794/what-is-the-definition-of-a-deductive-system) we have many terms with similar meaning.

Maybe the first one is [Formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language): an *alphabet* made of an initial (usually finite) stock of basic symbols and a set (usually finite) of rules to produce expressions (usually with finite length) that are called formulas.

With it we build a [Formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Formal_theories,_systems,_and_proofs) (also called a logical calculus, or a *logical system*) consisting of a formal language together with a deductive apparatus (also called a *deductive system*).

The deductive apparatus is a set (usually finite) of rules, called rules of inference, that we use to produce formulas from an initial stock of formulas: the axioms.

This is the syntactical part.

The logical system is used to derive *logical truths* (like e.g. $\vdash p \lor \lnot p$) and to derive consequences from assumptions: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

We may call it the "pure" logical theory.

When the set of assumptions $\Gamma$ is the formalized version of the collection of axioms of some mathematical theory, like e.g. the [firts-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) that formalizes the theory based on [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), we have an "applied" logical theory.

A formalized mathematical theory can be interpreted: for first-order arithmetic, the "natural" intepretation is the [mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) base on the set [$\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

The intuitive notion of interpretation, i.e. the way to assign meaning to symbols and formulas of a formal language, is made rigorous through the mathematical definition of [Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)) of a formal language.

This is the semantics.

Comment: Great answer. Let me add that the terminology used in Wikipedia's page about [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) is not standard and slightly misleading, especially in its definitions of "logical system".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for a great answer. Can you please recommend a good book with exercises to learn logic and everething you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @OlegDats - [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZWbsCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), [Chiswell and Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&printsec=frontcover), [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is the order of the books is the order of how should I study them?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am really interested in Philosophy, Theory of knowledge, and Artificial Intelligence. Any recommendation for a book (Logic is core) that also mentiones these topics?

Comment: @OlegDats - some sugesetions: Carlo Cellucci, [Rethinking Logic : Logic in Relation to Mathematics Evolution and Method (Springer, 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=TczHBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Carlo Cellucci, [Rethinking Knowledge: The Heuristic View (Springer, 2017)](https://books.google.it/books?id=KvyODgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Pavel Pudlak, [Logical Foundations of Mathematics and Computational Complexity (Springer, 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=obxDAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Harrie de Swart, [Philosophical and Mathematical Logic (Springer, 2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=0oF8DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Why is logic called a calculus?

Comment: @Buraian - see [Calculus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calculus#Etymology): "calculation; computation. Any formal system in which symbolic expressions are manipulated according to fixed rules: lambda calculus, predicate calculus."

Comment: Is all of mathematics then calculus? Because if one is to communicate they must use symbolic expa

Comment: @Buraian - not very clear... In principle, mathematics is not equal to "symbolic"; we can currently read Euclid's *Elements* and there are no formulas in modern terms. But modern mathematics blow up since Renaissance due to the "invention" of symbolic thinking.

Comment: I mean isn't language in itself a calculus by the type of definition you suggest